# auto update entreprise app

Tags: ios, appcelerator, auto-update

Im' looking for a process to auto update my entreprise distribution.

Two possible ways maybe.

1. My app check a script for the current release version available, and if the version on the device is lower then  I need a script who run the download of the new app release automaticly.
2. An other application who can check my current entreprise app version, and compare it with the current download version on a server, and if a new version is available, then download and install it.

I know that apple do it with the applestore and others service allow to do this with they own store.. like

http://www.apperian.com/mobile-application-management/enterprise-app-store/

But I dislike to use external services .. if they die .. my application will lose a necessary feature, that's why i try to do it myself

Thank for your help, i hope we can found a solution to improve appcelerator features !

Answer (score 0):

Try [Sparkle Framework](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/). Sparkle is an easy-to-use software update framework for Cocoa developers.

To setup Sparkle read [this documentation](https://github.com/andymatuschak/Sparkle/wiki)

Comment: For mobile application coded with titanium appcelerator ?

Comment: Sparkle is a native Objective - C framework. I guess you would be using html / css / javascript.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, I have look at Sparkle, and i maybe can implement it in titanium with a component, that a good way to investigate